# ThumbnailerJSONSerializer to representation returns self.context['request'], instance, KeyError: 'request'

Tags: python, django

I have

models.py

```
update_data = dict(topic=topic, subtopic=subtopic, chat_id=chat.id, message=VisitorMessageSerializer(m).data)
```

serializers.py

```
class VisitorMessageSerializer(NonNullModelSerializer):
     photo = ThumbnailerJSONSerializer(alias='core.Message.photo', read_only=True)
 class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['id', 'created_at', 'text', 'photo', 'author_agent',
                  'document', 'reply_markup', 'is_read', 'has_author', 'clientside_id']
```

here is a NonNullModelSerialzer:

```
class NonNullModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        result = super(NonNullModelSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        return OrderedDict([(key, result[key]) for key in result if result[key] is not None and result[key] != {}])
```

I can't get update_data because to_representation returns KeyError
to_representation
self.context['request'], instance,
KeyError: 'request'

Answer (score 0):

You have to add serializer context to serializer. In Generic view this is do automatically

It should be something like that:

```
update_data = dict(topic=topic, subtopic=subtopic, chat_id=chat.id, message=VisitorMessageSerializer(m, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data)
```

instead of `self.get_serializer_context()` you can pass `{'request': self.request}`